# PHP: HTML Dom Parser how to delete the <script> tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I get some  tag from the other site which I do parser.

Can I delete these  tags somehow?

I get these texts inside the content when I do echo "if (typeof zoneManager !== 'undefined') zoneManager.insertZone({key:'blabla', name:'blabla'});"

The script tag looks like on the other site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if (typeof zoneManager !== 'undefined') zoneManager.insertZone({key:'blabla', name:'blabla'}); </script>
```

My code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile($tartalom);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$h = "//div[@id='article-text']";
$c = "//h1";
$hirek = $xpath->query($h);
$cim = $xpath->query($c);

echo $hirek->item(0)->textContent;
```

Comment: can't you use `smallnews` class ?

Comment: What do you mean? I always get random numbers after smallnews contsrc_ and I want to specify the div tags one by one

Comment: you can loop throw smallnews selector element list

Comment: Ummm, I still don't know what do you mean. I am new into this for sure. Can you give me an example of the "loop throw" ?

Comment: bit confusing.what do you want to get ?you want to get the content inside  smallnews div?you want to get first 10 divs?you already have get divs what do you want specifically

Comment: I get the content inside these div classes from the other site now. But as I said these div classes contains random numbers after the contsrc_ text. And I want to specifically these 10 div tags. Something like this: $news1 = the first div what I got, $news2 = the second div what I got, etc... do you understand?

Comment: then you can use find again `$news=$html->find('div[class=smallnews]');$news[1];//first news selector`

Comment: I need to specify the full class name of the div in this way, else shows nothing... I can't specify the full class because I got random numbers from the other site after contsrc_  every time...

Comment: @n but why do you need to full class name ? `<div class="smallnews contsrc_861 h2_17">news</div>`  you can access a element by any selector why do you want to select it by random selector?

Comment: If I use this code: $news=$html->find('div[class=smallnews]');$news[1]; and do echo $news[1]; then shows nothing, but if I change the div class to e.g.: smallnews contsrc_861 h2_17 then shows the content of this div... it isn't possible to get the first smallnews class without specify the full class name?

Comment: try this https://pastebin.com/2h3MAwUd

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figured out with your help now works fine.

Can you help me a bit more please?

I wanna post the content to a wordpress page and I always get 500 error If I provide 'post_content' => $news[1], maybe because I'm trying to post an array string inside another array? or what? and how can I solve it then?

I'm using this example: https://www.kickstartcommerce.com/programmatically-create-wordpress-posts-pages-using-php.html

Comment: @ Nathan J   enable debug in wp-config file.then you can see the real error.what is the error?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I did changed the code a bit and now all works fine. But I got <script> tags inside the content. I edited my question check it please.